# The Mukai pairing

Tags: algebraic-geometry, derived-categories

I am reading the book “Fourier-Mukai transforms in algebraic geometry” by Daniel Huybrechts. at the end of the page 132 and the beginning of the page 133, he introduced the Mukai pairing as follows:

**Definition:** Let $\nu=\Sigma \nu_j\in \oplus H^j(X, \mathbb{C})$. Then one defines the dual of $\nu$ by
$$\nu^{\vee}:=\Sigma \sqrt{-1}^j\nu_j\in H^*(X,\mathbb{C})$$
and the Mukai pairing on $H^*(X,\mathbb{C})$ is the quadratic form
$$\langle\nu,\nu^{\vee}\rangle_X:=\int_X exp(c_1(X)/2).(\nu^{\vee}.\nu’)$$

Now, my question is that is there any reference that has some computations of the Mukai pairing? Or do you know any specific easy example of it?

Comment: K3 surface is the first example to work on. Huybrechts has another book _Geometry of Moduli of Sheaves_, co-authored with Lehn. You can find the computations there.

Comment: @AGlearner Thanks. I looked at that book but I couldn’t find any computation with details related to the Mukai pairing. May you address it a bit more accurate?

Comment: I don't know any reference better than that. For K3 surface, you know its Chern classes, its Todd class, the computation can be carried out more or less by yourself. For practical purpose, moduli of sheaves on K3 surfaces are classified by Mukai vectors. If you Google some key words, there are plenty of survey papers appear. Try to follow their computation would satisfy your need.

Answer (score 0):

On a CY surface, the pairing becomes $$\langle(v_0,v_1,v_2),(w_0,w_1,w_2)\rangle = v_0w_2 + v_2w_0 - v_1 w_1$$

For an abelian surface, the Mukai/Chern vector coincide since the tangent sheaf is trivial. You can then sanity check that the dimension $d$ of the stable line bundles of Chern $v=(1,0,0)$ should be $2$ (the dual abelian variety).

Indeed, put $E = \operatorname{Hom}(V,V)$ for such a stable $V$ of Chern $v$, and denote $ch(E)$ via $\operatorname{Hom}(v,v)$. Then the tangent space of $V$ in the moduli space is $H^1(E)$, and also $H^0(E) = H^2(E) = 1$ because $V$ is stable and Serre duality.

Then $\chi(v,v) = h^0 - h^1 + h^2 = 2 - d = \langle(1,0,0),(1,0,0)\rangle = 0$ so $d = 2$.

Comment: I've made some light typographical improvements - `\langle` and `\rangle` for brackets, `\operatorname{Hom}` for $\operatorname{Hom}$, and capitalizing some last names. Please keep these in mind for the future.